# How many time repeat each symbol

Tags: c#, string, linq

Can you help me write LINQ that calculate: how many each symbol in string? Like this?

```
String text="aaabbcccdde";
Dictionary<int,char> result=....//LINQ
foreach (var t in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} is met {1} times",t.symbol,t.times);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a little Linq:

```
var result = text.GroupBy(c => c)
                 .Select(g => new { symbol = g.Key, times = g.Count() });
foreach (var t in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} is met {1} times",t.symbol,t.times);
}
```

Or more simply

```
var result = text.GroupBy(c => c, (c, g) => new { symbol = c, times = g.Count() });
foreach (var t in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} is met {1} times",t.symbol,t.times);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = "aaabbcccdde";
foreach (var t in text.GroupBy(c => c))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} is met {1} times", t.Key, t.Count());
}
```

Where `Key` is the char that is being grouped and `Count()` is the number of times the `Key` appears.